# Find values from date in array

Tags: php, arrays

So i have been reading about `array_search`, `array_values` & `array_keys` but i cannot figure out how to search my array and put founded values in a new array.

I have `allYearData` array.
It looks likt this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 7811 [objekt_element] => 23050-121-1_3105 [objekt_nr] => 23050-121-1 [element_nr] => 3105 [vart] => B.Avf [vem] => Blå [anteckn] => [datum] => 2015-01-29 18:00:19 )
```

Now i´d like to split this array in part by dates.
so, search in the "key" "datum" and find all "values" ecual to: "2015-01-%"
 Put it in array: "janData".

So i tried this:

```
$janElementCount = array_search("2015-01-%", $allYearData);
print_r($janElementCount);
```

This won´t get me anything at all.
How come?

Comment: Google: `PHP preg_grep()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search()` match exact value you are looking for PHP [**preg_grep()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

```
$janElementCount = preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $allYearData[0]);
```

**Note:** Because your array is at `[0]` position so pass `$allYearData[0]`.

See working [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/449790)

Comment: Thank you. Regarding to the manual this looks like what i need. But is the "charaters" correct? because i get no hits... hmm...

Comment: Updated my answer try `$janElementCount = preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $allYearData[0]);`.

Comment: Ok. Now it works a bit ;) `preg_grep("/v(\w+)/", $allYearData[0]);` finds me [vart] => B.Avf. But: `"/^2015-01-.*$/"` finds me nothing.

Comment: Also i need to make a loop.. Because there are more data than this in the array. [0]-[8000]

Comment: But for me its giving correct output. I have added demo in answer.

Comment: My bad. I now got it working. Thank you very much. If you have the time, can you please add up how to search the whole array.. not just [0]

Comment: Then you need to iterate each element with loop.

Comment: Maby it´s just better to do 12 querys, instead of putting all data in one array and then cut it apart... hmmm

Comment: No its not good approach to query 12 times. Always better approach to query minimum times for getting desired data. In your case querying one time and manipulating data is best then querying multiple times.